# Delete Panel within inside another panel

Tags: vb.net, controls, panel

I have a Panel that, in turn, has 4 panels inside. The interior panels are named "XXXX | 1 | A", "XXXX | 1 | B", "XXXX | 1 | C" and "XXXX | 1 | D", as you can see to differentiate them in the last character it has a letter.

In this case, what I want to do is always delete only the panels that are identified as A and B.

***This is my code.***

```
Dim clickedLabel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)

pb = clickedLabel.Parent
Dim controls_number As Integer = pb.Controls.Count
Dim spliterb
Dim con As Control

For Each con In pb.Controls

    spliterb = con.Name.Split("|")

    If spliterb(2).ToString = ("A") Or spliterb(2).ToString = ("B") Then
       pb.Controls.Remove(con)
    End If

Next
```

As you can see, with the variable controls_number I know that there are 4 Panels inside, but when going through the arrangement, it only reads 3 and only removes the Panel that is identified as B and does not reach Panel A.

Can you explain to me why you don't read the 4 Panels? Any ideas for me to go through all 4?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't EVER modify a list while enumerating it with a `For Each` loop. The simple solution in this and many other cases is to extract the items you want into a separate list and loop through that while removing the items from the original list. The removal will thus have no effect on the list that you're enumerating. In your case, that might look like this:

```vb
Dim panels = pb.Controls.
                OfType(Of Panel)().
                Where(Function(pnl) pnl.Name.EndsWith("|A") OrElse
                                    pnl.Name.EndsWith("|B")).
                ToArray()

For Each pnl In panels
    pnl.Dispose()
Next
```

Calliing `Dispose` will remove the control from its parent and properly dispose it. If you just call `Remove` then the control is not disposed. Unless you intend to reuse the control, that's bad.

Comment: excellent answer, I'm applying your answer. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the original list is enumerated in its entirety first, in order to create the secondary list, and then the secondary list is enumerated. That does make this option less efficient than the alternative but it would be very rare that the difference would be worth worrying about. You'd need both lists to be very large or else be doing this for a very large number of lists for it to matter. Generally speaking, writing concise code should be your primary aim and you should only worry specifically about performance if it's a genuine issue.

Comment: one more question, in this case if I need to delete the panel, since I must generate a new one but with other attributes, I see that Dispose () is being used, but it does not delete the object as such, it only resets, if I try to use Remove (), obviously it will ask me for the controls part, is it possible to change it?
From the list yes, although in this case it will always be 4, so I don't think there is a problem. Greetings.

Comment: @LARC, it don't really know what you're saying. There is no resetting going on regardless and there's no such thing as deleting. You can remove the control from its parent and you can dispose the control, which means releasing its resources. The object still exists regardless. The point is that removing doesn't dispose but disposing does remove. Unless you want to reuse the child control, simply call its `Dispose` method, otherwise call `Remove` on the parent `Controls` collection and you can re-add them later.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot rename a Control with a pipe Char “|” as it’s not allowed by designer.
However in example below I assume it was an underscore Char “_”.
Now when you are loopping a collection if it’s change her dimension during this loop you are losing the number of elements (you remove) after the new length/dimension.
So to do that you can use as a trick looping the inverse (by max dimension to 0) in this case the  remaining elements are always inside/present in your loop.

The piece of code below shows what I mean.

```
    For i As Integer = pb.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If pb.Controls(i).Name Like "*_A" OrElse pb.Controls(i).Name Like "*_B" Then
            pb.Controls.Remove(pb.Controls(i))
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: The `Name` property of a control is just a `String`, so anything is allowed. You cannot use a name like that in the designer because that also causes a field to be declared with the same name and a pipe is not allowed in an identifier. If you create controls at run time though, there's no corresponding field so restrictions on identifiers don't apply.

Comment: Yes @jmcilhinney by designer I mean. I’m going to add this as detail. :). Good approach yours above. I like it ;).

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, simple and easy your answer, thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, one question more, I tried to execute the two criteria, that is, both A and B or C and D could be erased, when I execute A and B, it does it, but when I execute C and D, it jumps them, any different criteria that make did not take them into account?

Comment: @LARC Just add Like `"*_C"` or Like `"*_D"` in your if clause

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, yes I did, but it doesn't read those values

Comment: It's not possible... note that, need to be exactly  `Like "*_C"`

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, Yes I know, I change the criteria by a variable, to do dynamically `Like varA` and varA could change to `"*_A" or "*_C"`

Comment: @LARC If the letter `“C”` is at the end use `"*_C"` if it’s at the start use `"C_*"` if it’s in the midle you need to use `"*_C_*"`

Comment: Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator how to use operator `Like`

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, OK, I understand and it's working, thank you so much.